# List layers in directory .Net ArcObjects or plain .Net  -- C# preferably

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-engine, c#, .net

Any code samples to list arcgis layer files from a directory so they can be looped over?

Answer (score 3):

Using a windows form, button, and listbox you could use this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Try
            ' make a reference to a directory
            Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("c:\temp")
            Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*.lyr*")
            Dim dra As IO.FileInfo

            'list the names of all files in the specified directory
            For Each dra In diar1
                ListBox1.Items.Add(dra.Name)
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error " & ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: @Justin, You can use this website to convert between vb and c#, http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Answer (score 3):

This should be easy to convert to C#, it is still .NET. Make sure to mark what artwork posted as the answer if it gives you the expected results.

```
try
{
  DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp");
  FileInfo diar1 = new di.GetFiles("*.lyr*");

  foreach(FileInfo dra in diar1)
  {
    ListBox1.Items.Add(dra.Name);
  }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   //do something with exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following function goes through a directory, gets a list of all the XML files, sorts the list by name, then writes the filenames of the XML files out to a text file. It does a little more than you need, but the principal is there of looping through the directory and doing something with the files - just another way to go about it.

```
public static void make_enerdeq_filelist(Constants c)
// Create Enerdeq_Filelist.txt to feed our ETL job
{
    // Kill Enerdeq_Filelist.txt if it exists
    if (File.Exists(c.infaServer + c.fileList))
    {
        File.Delete(c.infaServer + c.fileList);
    }
    // Sort files by name-alpha, INFA wants sorted input
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(c.infaServer);
    StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(c.infaServer + c.fileList);
    string[] xml_files = Directory.GetFiles(c.infaServer);
    IComparer comp = new FileComparer(FileComparer.CompareBy.Name);
    Array.Sort(xml_files, comp);
    foreach (string xml_file in xml_files)
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(xml_file);
        string file_name = fi.Name;
        if (file_name.EndsWith(".xml"))  // XML files only
        {
            sw.WriteLine(file_name);
            sw.Flush();
        }
    }
    sw.Close();
}
```